# Is there a way to extend xdg-open?

Tags: xdg-open

I hope the title is not misleading.

I am using an note taking app that let's me open files from markdown notes:

> ```
> [read more](/path/to/file.pdf)
> ```

I couldn't find a way to open it at a specific page. I cannot create a link in The format which the PDF reader accepts.

Is there a good way I can open files with a script? Basically I want to replace `#page=5` with `-p 5` every time.

I thought I could write my own wrapper script such that I can type:

> ```
> [read more](/path/to/file.pdf#page=5)
> ```

and my script parses the path and transforms it into

> ```
>  xdg-open /path/to/file.pdf -p 5
> ```

Comment: Just curious, what app do you use for Markdown?

Comment: I am using https://boostnote.io/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how elegant is the method below. But it works normally for me.

I'm using [ReText](https://github.com/retext-project/retext) as Markdown editor and plan to use

```
[link-to-pdf](pdf-filename.pdf#page=2)
```

syntax for PDF with page number.

So I have defined my local `xdg-open` wrapper script:

```
mkdir /home/$USER/bin
echo "export PATH=/home/$USER/bin:$PATH" >> .bashrc
```

and placed the following code to `/home/$USER/bin/xdg-open`:

```
#!/bin/sh

pdfviewer=atril
filename="$1";

case $filename in
    *.pdf#page=*) 
            file=$(echo "$filename" | cut -d "#" -f 1);
            page=$(echo "$filename" | cut -d "#" -f 2 | sed "s/page=/-p /");
            $pdfviewer "$file" $page ;;
    *)      /usr/bin/xdg-open "$@" ;;
esac
```

This script should be executable (set with `chmod +x /home/$USER/bin/xdg-open`), and it will be used only if `.pdf#page=` will be found, otherwise it will use system-wide `/usb/bin/xdg-open`.

I have tested this method with Atril PDF viewer on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS MATE.
You can change `pdfviewer` variable to `evince` if you want.

As free bonus we can use the `.pdf#page=` syntax in the terminal:

```
xdg-open /usr/share/doc/qpdf/qpdf-manual.pdf#page=12
```

---

Note: after such manipulations we have two `xdg-open` executables - the output of `whereis xdg-open` should become `xdg-open: /usr/bin/xdg-open /home/user/bin/xdg-open /usr/share/man/man1/xdg-open.1.gz`.

Comment: +1 but usually `$@` is double quoted `"$@"` I think. Same should apply for `"$"` and `"$filename"` I believe. Otherwise filenames with a space would be considered two different file names split on the space.

Comment: @linuxUser123 Thanks for confirmation. N0bert the `"$"` above should read `"$1"`. Have too many things on the go tonight :)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix thanks. See edit above. Is it enough / correct?

Comment: @N0rbert Welcome. Looks perfect to my three beer eyes :)

Comment: @linuxUser123 fixed :)